# Disable auto-login after password reset laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a web application that uses Laravel's auth to handle the user's authentication, however a user cannot sign in without verifying his email, while testing the auth pages I realized that after reseting the password the user gets signed-in anyway, I tried to disable it however I was unable to figure out what method to override

I saw this post [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524973/avoid-auto-login-when-password-is-reset), the only post on the internet based on my search for the better part of my day that still uses the default laravel ResetPasswordController and has auto-login disable however the solution did not match what I was looking for

If anyone can help me override the method I need or point me to the file in which I need to change I would hihgly appreciate it

I have already overridden the rules() method but cannot figure out what the other method is

```
    protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ];
}
```

Right now this is my `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController.php`

```
<?php
/*************************************************
Namespace 
*************************************************/
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

/*************************************************
Import laravel classes 
*************************************************/
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

/*************************************************
Class
*************************************************/
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords;
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ];
    }
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
}
```

After trying to change my controller to

```
<?php
/*************************************************
Namespace 
*************************************************/
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

/*************************************************
Import laravel classes 
*************************************************/
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;

/*************************************************
Class
*************************************************/
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    //use ResetsPasswords;
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ];
    }
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password) {
    $this->setUserPassword($user, $password);

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    // Comment or remove the line below.
    // $this->guard()->login($user);
    }
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
}
```

trying to reset the password threw this error

```
BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController::showResetForm does not exist.
```

Highly appreciated
Thank you

Comment: this is located on `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController.php`

Comment: yes but this does not include the method I desire, let me edit the whole NewPasswordController.php method, I am looking for the method that has the auth()->guard() that usually signs people in, if not at least find a way to disable auto login

Comment: Which Authentication system you are using? Currently laravel has auth/ui, breeze and fortify Authentication

Comment: Alright I just checked and I am using auth/ui

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: I am using laravel 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are still using the `ResetPasswords` trait even though this is in a different file. Override the `resetPassword` method in your controller.

```
use ResetPasswords;

/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
 * @param  string  $password
 * @return void
 */
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $this->setUserPassword($user, $password);

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    // Comment or remove the line below.
    // $this->guard()->login($user);
}
```

Note: You didn't change the class name of your `NewPasswordController.php` file.

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect the change and the result

Comment: Retain the usage of `ResetPasswords` trait.

Comment: But this will cause the error "Undefined method" for both `$user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));` and `$user->save();` and user still gets signed in

Comment: Thank you very much, for some reason VS code keeps on giving an error, despite that the code works, looks like an ide problem

Comment: Don't forget to add this in your includes:
use Illuminate\Support\Str;